# Change password on Ubuntu client using LDAP Authentication

Tags: 14.04, password, authentication, ldap

I've setup a computer lab running Ubuntu 14 clients and an Ubuntu 14 server.

The clients are successfully logging in using credentials provided by Open LDAP. I used this guide to configure the clients - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication

I would like to enable each user to change their password at the client.

I've tried the usual ways to change password -

1. Through System Settings, but need to login as root user to "unlock" User panel
2. Through terminal - passwd. I get "Authentication information cannot be recovered"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First, the server ACLs should allow the user to modify their own password. Do they? You would probably have applied an ACL like the first one at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-acl.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, work has been crazy so sorry for not getting back sooner, that page has a lot of info and I'll try to work it out. Do you know if it is possible to enable this through phpLDAPadmin?

Answer (score 0):

In client system edit file

```
/etc/pam.d/common-password
```

and remove the word `auth_key`.